# How to use external asm function in "vscode-amiga-debug" cross compiler?

Tags: assembly, amiga, c

I would like to write functions in assembly along with the c source code, but somehow I can't find the syntax.
I tried e.g. in the fname.asm file (simplified):

```
fill_bmap:
        rts
```

In the fname.c source:

```
extern void fill_bmap();
```

But the compiler gives this error message:

> undefined reference to `fill_bmap'

Comment: So this is a “how do I use some modern software” question?

Answer (score 9):

There are two caveats involved when mixing C and assembly:

1. You must tell the assembler that a symbol is meant to be externally visible (so that the linker can see it). With *vasm*, there are several ways to do that depending on the language mode you are using. To make <`symbol`> known externally, you might have to use one of the following directives (I have ordered them in falling order of probability):

   ```
   XDEF    symbol
   .global symbol
   extern  symbol
   public  symbol
   ```
2. Some (many) C compilers for historical and other reasons tend to prepend an underscore to external symbols, so, when you're calling a function named

   ```
       extfunc ()
   ```

   from your C code, the linker will actually look for an assembly symbol named

   ```
       _extfunc
   ```

   So you might have to rename your assembly function depending on the C compiler you are using.

Comment: Thanks for the info, it was helpful.
In the meantime, I also realized that the Makefile also needs to be entered
source file, e.g.:
s_sources := bitmap_fill.s

Comment: I was actually assuming you had already done that. Maybe assumed too much. What's not in the Makefile is not going to be translated...